# How to validate that an uploaded file is complete

Tags: validation, csv, upload

I have an system with which users can upload a CSV file via an FTP server, or via a html form. On my end, a script polls the uploads directory and processes new files found. Some users will create the CSV by exporting it from Excel, while others will programmatically create it with scripts of their own.

My concern at the moment is: How can I be 100% certain that the file my processing script acts on is complete - in other words that it isn't a partial file (in progress, failed upload, etc)?

If the file format was something more structured, like XML, I'd be 100% confident that the file is complete by checking that the XML structure is valid (ie: closing tags).

Is there a good way to ensure that the uploaded CSV file is complete, **without burdening & confusing less technical users** who are simply uploading a file exported from a spreadsheet program (ie: providing an md5 of the file contents would be beyond them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing CSV file formats in the past, I've always added a header and footer line as follows:

```
id,one,two,three,four,five,six
10,1,2,3,4,5,6
11,1,2,3,4,5,6
12,1,2,3,4,5,6
13,1,2,3,4,5,6
14,1,2,3,4,5,6
FOOTER,5
```

Most CSV file formats have a header to label the columns, the purpose of the footer is to indicate the file is completed. The footer contains a simple line count, which is easy to audit when looping through the file's contents. Not too complicated for users.

Comment: I think this is probably the best approach, and is fairly simple for end users.

Answer (score 0):

You could crosscheck whenever the filesize of the uploaded file matches the filesize of the original file.

Comment: This would be somewhat easy to do with a file uploaded via an html+php form, as I'll have access to the original file attributes. However, I'm not sure how I'd do this with a file being uploaded by FTP.

Comment: True. You should be able to make your server save information upon initlation of upload, maybe into an database (filename, id, filesize) When your endscript validates and converts, make it get details from the database and check it against the file for validation.